# InLine IIF Expression & DataBinder.Eval not operating as expected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, codeblocks

I'm trying to strip characters from the end of a string using `.tostring.remove(n)`. with the code below the `IIf` statement confirms the string is ISNullOrEmpty and returns `True` or `False`. If `true` is returned the string of `""` is placed in the aspx page (this works fine), the problem arises in the second part which is triggered when the IsNullOrEmpty returns `False`.

Upon a `False` value the strings length is checked, if the string is equal to or more than 17 characters long the a `True` value is returned and the string is truncated using the `.ToString.Remove(n)` if a `False` value is returned then the string is left untouched.

the problem is that if the string is 1 character or 20 characters long the following error keeps occurring:
`startIndex must be less than length of string`

here is the code block:

```
<%# IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SponsorEmail"))),
"",
IIf(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SponsorEmail")).Length > 17,
Eval("SponsorEmail").ToString.Remove(17),
Eval("SponsorEmail")))%>
```

The database tables the databinder is drawing it's data from does allow NULLS, and it only happens when a NULL or Empty string is present for any given record.

Help Please, it's driving me nuts!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having with `iif` is that the entire statement is evaluated every time, not just the true or false part. This means that the `Remove(17)` is being fired every time, regardless of what the condition evaluates to.

You can prove this with the following code:

```
    Dim sValue = IIf(Nothing, DoEval("true"), DoEval("false"))
    Console.WriteLine("Final " & sValue)

Private Function DoEval(value As String) As String
    Console.WriteLine(value)
    Return value
End Function
```

In this case, you will see both true and false written to the output window.

We had so many issues introduced through the use of `iif` that we have banned its use in our applications.

You would be much better off switching to a traditional `if then else` clause.

Comment: So pleased you told me this, I wold have spent many more hours trying to understand why it was trying to perform that part of the code when the string wasn't long enough....